# Android custom layout for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I may be missing something simple here, but I have an **AutoCompleteTextView** that contains some very long items. When one is clicked, it shows the text correctly in the EditText and spans it over several lines.

However, I want it to be in multiple lines on the popup as well so that the users can see which item they are selecting.

Here is my custom layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Here is my initialisation of the array and adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.dropdown_item_wrap_line,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.building_descriptions));

mBuildingDesc.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Do you need multiple rows within an element? I mean a single view within AutoCompleteTextView should contain two rows and you will use second row to show some other information? I am I right?

Comment: Sorry no, I just mean for one view that wraps around rather than cutting off, my items can be quite long (eg "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies tempus neque, nec egestas erat tincidunt et. ")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that your `AutoCompleteTextView` is limited to `singleLine`, so using a custom layout with default `TextView` should work neatly.

You will need to make a new `Layout` and name it `custom_item.xml`, then do it like this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"    
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then while using Adapter on AutoCompleteTextView do

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_item, R.id.autoCompleteItem, StringArray);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This works how ever, if you are going to get the text of the item you could have a problem. So first you set your setOnItemClickListener, then the param View view, is no longer a TextView but a LinearLayout.

Comment: i do not think so, i used custom arrayAdapter and it works with single lines although i did not check with custom layout. i m going to check and update it here :)